# Reading request: induced representations & fiber bundles

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

To my understanding, the theory of induced representations of a group $G$ can be formulated in terms of vector bundles associated with the group considered as a principal bundle ${G \to G/H }$.

I'm wondering if there's any good reading on this topic, accessible to a physicist having some knowledge of representation theory and topology.

Answer (score 1):

The currently-standard book by Kanuth and Taylor
https://academic.oup.com/blms/article-abstract/46/3/658/2255098
was written by mathematicians and for mathematicians.  Its language is difficult for a physicist.

However, browsing the web, I came across these wonderful lectures
http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~jmf/Teaching/Projects/Poincare/IndReps.pdf

I wouldn't call them bed-time reading, but they are certainly accessible to a physicist.